# Disable scroll event on browser resize

Tags: javascript, jquery, window-resize

So I have a basic script that applies a fixed class to a div (.filter-target) when the user scrolls past a certain point of the page. What I would like to know is how I can disable the scroll event if the user resizes their browser and the width of the browser is <1100px (i.e. the minWidth variable).

```
var app = {};

app.filter = (function() {
    var module = {};

    var $filter = $('.filter-target');
 // Creates a spacer, this is to push the content of the page down the same size of the floating menu
    var $filterSpacer = $('<div />', {
        "class": "filter-drop-spacer",
        "height": $filter.outerHeight()
    });

    var minWidth = Modernizr.mq('only screen and (min-width: 1100px)');
    var windowWidth = $(window).width();

    module.init = function() {

        var fixedFilter = function() {
            $filter
                .before($filterSpacer)
            .addClass("is-fixed") 
            .css('width', $('.page-content').width());
        };

        var relativeFilter = function() {
            $filter
                .removeClass("is-fixed")
                .css('width', '');

            $filterSpacer.remove(); 
        };

        var filterController = function() {
            if (minWidth == true) {
                if (!$filter.hasClass('is-fixed') && $(window).scrollTop() > $filter.offset().top) {
                    // Checks the filter doesn't have the class fix and that vertical number of pixels hidden is greater than the navigations position on the page. This will get executed the first time the page scrolls past the point. I.E When you scroll hits the menu.
                    fixedFilter();
                } else if ($filter.hasClass('is-fixed') && $(window).scrollTop() < $filterSpacer.offset().top) {
                    // If the navigation element has the fix class and that vertical number of pixels hidden is less than the top of the newly added spacer. I.E When you scroll UP past the spacer.
                    relativeFilter();
                }
            } else {
                relativeFilter();
            }
        };

        $(window).scroll(function() {
            filterController();
        });

    };

    return module;
})();

$(document).ready(function() {
    app.filter.init();
    console.log('filter');
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make it happen with the resize event

At the beginning set minWidth

```
var minWidth = true;
```

On resize make it false

```
$( window ).resize(function() {
    if( $(window).width() < 1100){
       minWidth = false;
    }    
});
```

Comment: Thanks - but how would I actually go about disabling it? Presumably firing relativeFilter()?

Comment: You can change minWidth to false on resize and if the width is less than 1100, otherwise it will be true :)

Comment: I used the modernizr variable to get an accurate browser width rather than $(window).width() but it works the same! Thanks